# Why is 8:05 "time to rock"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In Sammy Hagar's song ["There's Only One Way To Rock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_Only_One_Way_to_Rock) there is a line that goes:

> Now quickly, check the hands on the clock
>   It's 8:05, it's time to rock

So my question is: **why is 8:05 time to rock?** That is very specific and I'm not familiar with any kind of cultural meaning behind the number/time. Or did he just choose whatever time it was when he wrote the lyric?

Answer (score 1):

The more likely explanation is that is he's referring to starting a concert at that time in a slightly tongue-in-cheek fashion. Most concerts will start between 7-10 depending on scheduling, and rockers typically aren't the most punctual people, and if a concert is scheduled to start at 8:00, 8:05 would probably be the time the show starts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good explanation:

[Sammy Hagar’s “There’s Only One Way To Rock” And Its Relation To The Subject’s Schedule: A Critical Analysis](http://web.archive.org/web/20160802150636/http://theimpersonals.com/2013/11/08/sammy-hagars-theres-only-one-way-to-rock-and-its-relation-to-the-subjects-schedule-a-critical-analysis/)

> In his 1981 hit “There’s Only One Way to Rock,” Sammy Hagar outlines the very specific criteria in making rocking possible. However, Mr. Hagar never explicitly defines or describes this singularly hypothesized way of rock. He, does, however, state the exact, proper time to rock: 8:05 (as in the lyric, “8:05, time to rock.”) This is a surprisingly early, yet extremely specific time for rocking, which warrants a full audit of Mr. Hagar’s schedule and a rundown of obligations which should also answer the underlying question: Why is Sammy Hagar, a man so clearly and publicly dedicated to rocking, unable to rock until shortly, and specifically, just after 8 p.m?

...

> But at 8:05, the responsibilities of the day have been completed, and Mr. Hagar’s soul, spirit, and physical being are sufficiently prepared to rock. Mr. Hagar then affirmatively states – to himself, but often out loud – that it’s “8:05, time to rock.”
>
> At this time, Mr. Hagar rocks.

Comment: I ran across that too. Entertaining but completely tongue in cheek. I'd like to know an answer that can be cited either by Sammy giving an explanation or  something along those lines.

Comment: Please don't just put a link as an answer.  Make sure the important parts of the answer are on this site incase the link rots.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for the opening act to take the stage at 7:00 p.m. and play for 45 minutes. After a 20 minute set change, the headline act would take the stage at 8:05.   \m/

Comment: I've never been to a rock concert that started at 7:00